# How to determine GC workstation vs server mode from dump file

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, crash-dumps, sos, windb

From a dump file, is it possible to determine that Garbage collection mode used server vs workstation)? If so, what command?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `!eeversion` SOS extension command.  Sample output:

```
2.0.50727.8009 retail
Workstation mode
SOS Version: 4.0.30319.34014 retail build
```

Second line tells you.